What can I use as an alternative to a RefreshView in my MAUI app?
I'm working on a .NET MAUI app that I've recently started to test on iOS. While there were no issues with a RefreshView while testing on Android, I've noticed it has caused multiple issues on iOS. Three pages have a RefreshView, which all have a nested CollectionView and I've noticed the following randomly occur

I cannot scroll the CollectionView
The CollectionView is only showing half of the items
The left margin is positioned along the center of the screen, pushing everything to the right

I've tried changing the vertical and horizontal options on the RefreshView and CollectionView, I debugged to see if some data was failing to load, and I looked into why a CollectionView may not be scrolling on an iOS device. I deleted the RefreshView on each page and all of the aforementioned issues went away, however I would like to have the refresh functionality. What's something else I could implement to have the same functionality, or how could I possibly fix these issues with the RefreshView on iOS?
Here's an example of a RefreshView with a nested Collection View:
<RefreshView x:Name="RefreshFeed" Grid.Row="3" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}" RefreshColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextColor}" Refreshing="RefreshTheFeed">
    <CollectionView x:Name="MsgList" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="GoMsg">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
                        <On Platform="WinUI,iOS">
                            <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding otherUser.profileImgSrc}" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFit" Margin="20"/>
                        </On>
                        <On Platform="Android">
                            <Frame Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}" BorderColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Margin="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Image Source="{Binding otherUser.profileImgSrc}" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </On>
                    </OnPlatform>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding otherUser.FullName}" TextColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextColor}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="20, 10, 20, 10"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding LocalLastMsgSent, StringFormat='{0:MMMM d, yyyy} at {0:h:mm tt}'}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="8" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="20, 10, 20, 10"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding lastMsg}" TextColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryTextColor}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="20, -10, 0, 10">
                        <Label.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding newMsg}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding newMsg}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="None"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Label.Triggers>
                    </Label>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</RefreshView>


Please add some relevant code in your question to help the community reproduce the issue.

I just posted an example

Have you tried Load data incrementally?

And I cannot reproduce this question based on your code. Could you please share more code? or add some pictures to show the actual behavior and the expected result?

@LiqunShen-MSFT iOS CollectionView has an issue with the RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand and RemainingItemsThresholdReached it does not trigger check this https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10078

@FreakyAli Thank you for the link. This issue happens only when using grouped data for CollectionView. Maybe I should wait for op sharing more code.

@JackStapleton Could you please also share the relevant code for the parent layout of the RefreshView?
